# MDC logging for SSHD server with custom, per-company file-system

Tags: java, sshd, apache-mina

We are using Apache-Mina SSHD 1.7 to expose a SFTP server that uses a custom file-system implementation which creates a file system per company. So users of the same company (or more precisely for the same connector) will access the same file system while a users of an other company will access a filesystem unique to their company. The file-system is moreover just a view on a MySQL database and will write uploaded files after some conversions directly into the DB and read files on download from the DB.

The setup of the server looks like the excerpt below

```
void init() {
    server = MessageSftpServer.setUpDefaultServer();
    server.setPort(port);
    LOG.debug("Server is configured for port {}", port);

    File pemFile = new File(pemLocation);
    FileKeyPairProvider provider = new FileKeyPairProvider(pemFile.toPath());
    validateKeyPairProvider(provider.loadKeys(), publicKeyList);
    server.setKeyPairProvider(provider);
    server.setCommandFactory(new ScpCommandFactory());
    server.setPasswordAuthenticator(
        (String username, String password, ServerSession session) -> {
            ...
        });

    PropertyResolverUtils.updateProperty(server, ServerAuthenticationManager.MAX_AUTH_REQUESTS, 3);

    SftpSubsystemFactory sftpFactory = new SftpSubsystemFactory.Builder()
        .withShutdownOnExit(false)
        .withUnsupportedAttributePolicy(UnsupportedAttributePolicy.Warn)
        .build();
    server.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(sftpFactory));
    // add our custom virtual file system to trick the user into believing she is operating against
    // a true file system instead of just operating against a backing database
    server.setFileSystemFactory(
        new DBFileSystemFactory(connectorService, companyService, mmService, template));
    // filter connection attempts based on remote IPs defined in connectors
    server.addSessionListener(whitelistSessionListener);
}
```

Within the file system factory we basically just create the URI for the file system provider and pass it to the respective method of it

```
@Override
public FileSystem createFileSystem(Session session) throws IOException {

    SFTPServerConnectorEntity connector =
    connectorService.getSFTPServerConnectorForUser(session.getUsername());
    if (null == connector) {
        throw new IOException("No SFTP Server connector found for user " + session.getUsername());
    }
    String ip = CommonUtils.getIPforSession(session);
    URI fsUri = URI.create("dbfs://" + session.getUsername() + "@" + ip + "/" + connector.getUuid());

    LOG.debug("Checking whether to create file system for user {} connected via IP {}",
        session.getUsername(), ip);

    Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("UserAgent", session.getClientVersion());

    try {
        return fileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(fsUri, env);
    } catch (FileSystemAlreadyExistsException fsaeEx) {
        LOG.debug("Reusing existing filesystem for connector {}", connector.getUuid());
        return fileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(fsUri);
    }
}
```

and within the provider we simply parse the values from the provided URI and environment variables to create the final filesystem if none was yet available within the cache

```
@Override
public DBFileSystem newFileSystem(URI uri, Map<String, ?> env) throws IOException {
    LOG.trace("newFileSystem({}, {}))", uri, env);
    ConnectionInfo ci = ConnectionInfo.fromSchemeSpecificPart(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart());
    String cacheKey = generateCacheKey(ci);

    synchronized (fileSystems) {
        if (fileSystems.containsKey(cacheKey)) {
            throw new FileSystemAlreadyExistsException(
                "A filesystem for connector " + ci.getConnectorUuid()
                    + " connected from IP " + ci.getIp() + " already exists");
        }
    }

    SFTPServerConnectorEntity connector =
        connectorService.get(SFTPServerConnectorEntity.class, ci.getConnectorUuid());
    List<CompanyEntity> companies = companyService.getCompaniesForConnector(connector);
    if (companies.size() < 1) {
        throw new IOException("No company for connector " + connector.getUuid() + " found");
    }

    DBFileSystem fileSystem = null;
    synchronized (fileSystems) {
        if (!fileSystems.containsKey(cacheKey)) {
            LOG.info("Created new filesystem for connector {} (Remote IP: {}, User: {}, UserAgent: {})",
                ci.getConnectorUuid(), ci.getIp(), ci.getUser(), env.get("UserAgent"));
            fileSystem = new DBFileSystem(this, connector.getUsername(), companies, connector,
                template, ci.getIp(), (String) env.get("UserAgent"));
            Pair<DBFileSystem, AtomicInteger> sessions =  Pair.of(fileSystem, new AtomicInteger(1));
            fileSystems.put(cacheKey, sessions);
        }
    }

    if (null == fileSystem) {
        throw new FileSystemAlreadyExistsException(
            "A filesystem for connector " + ci.getConnectorUuid()
                + " connected from IP " + ci.getIp() + " already exists");
    }

    return fileSystem;
}

@Override
public DBFileSystem getFileSystem(URI uri) {
    LOG.trace("getFileSystem({}))", uri);
    String schemeSpecificPart = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();

    if (!schemeSpecificPart.startsWith("//")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Invalid URI provided. URI must have a form of 'dbfs://ip:port/connector-uuid' where "
                + "'ip' is the IP address of the connected user, 'port'  is the remote port of the user and "
                + "'connector-uuid' is a UUID string identifying the connector the filesystem was created for");
    }

    ConnectionInfo ci = ConnectionInfo.fromSchemeSpecificPart(schemeSpecificPart);
    String cacheKey = generateCacheKey(ci);

    if (!fileSystems.containsKey(cacheKey)) {
        throw new FileSystemNotFoundException(
            "No filesystem found for connector " + ci.getConnectorUuid() + " with connection from IP "
                + ci.getIp());
    }
    Pair<DBFileSystem, AtomicInteger> sessions = fileSystems.get(cacheKey);
    if (!sessions.getKey().isOpen()) {
        throw new FileSystemNotFoundException(
            "Filesystem for connector " + ci.getConnectorUuid() + " with connection from IP " + ci
                .getIp() + " was closed already");
    }
    int curSessions = sessions.getValue().incrementAndGet();
    LOG.info("Added further session to filesystem for connector {}. Current connected sessions: {} (Remote IP: {}, User: {})",
        ci.getConnectorUuid(), curSessions, ci.getIp(), ci.getUser());

    return sessions.getKey();
}

private String generateCacheKey(String user, String ip, String connectorUuid) {
    return connectorUuid + "_" + ip + "_" + user;
}

private String generateCacheKey(ConnectionInfo ci) {
    return generateCacheKey(ci.getUser(), ci.getIp(), ci.getConnectorUuid());
}
```

This works out really well, however, as more and more users get added to the SFTP server the monitoring of the performed actions is suffering a bit due to the lack of propper MDC logging. Simply adding MDC logging isn't working cleanly as Mina or SSHD in particular share the threads among connected users which lead to the MDC context printing the wrong information at times which further lead to confusion on analyzing the log. As a temporary solution we removed it currently from the project.

We also tried to customize `Nio2Session` (and a couple of other classes) in order to intervene into the threading creation, though this classes were obviously not designed for inheritance which later lead to problems down the road.

Is there a better strategy to include propper MDC logging in our particular scenario where not one file system is used but a filesystem per company approach?

Comment: Have you seen [MdcInjectionFilter](http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch5-filters/ch5-filters.html)? If it works well, one can write a similar filter I think.

Comment: @m4gic I'd love to try it but I have yet to find an option on how to add it actually to the server. The documentation here is a bit sparse and I guess I already tried almost all of the possible options without any success. SSHD builds up on MINA though hides its internal successfully. This was especially clear after digging into IoSession, which SSHD has its own one ...

Comment: @RomanVottner Did you find an answer?

Comment: @RamaAdaikkalam Unfortunately, I'm not longer part of the messaging team that had to deal with those issues and as such I do not have access to the current state of the code. I have found some backup of a previous state though but the code I've added is probably to large for the comment section and not appropriate enough for an answer as I'm still not sure whether that solved our issues or not. Basically I wrote a `LoggingAdvice` class that implemented an `AutoCloseable` interface, set all the MDC properties manually and unset them on closing

Comment: @RamaAdaikkalam This `LoggingAdvice` was then used in combination within a try-with-resources block anywhere where a `Session` or our custom file system was used, i.e. our custom FileChannel, FileSystem, FileSystemProvider, FileSystemFactory and SFTP server implementations besides PublickeyAuthenticator or PasswordAuthenticator implementations